# Explaining a pun or nick-name from a Manning Coles thriller

Tags: meaning, wordplay, manning-coles, tommy-hambledon-series

Recently I have read, or re-read, a number of the old thrillers by Manning Coles. In the book *With Intent to Deceive* (1947—published in the United States as *A Brother for Hugh*), I ran into this bit of filler that puzzled me completely:

> “Mr. Quint,” began Bagshott.
> “Samuel Quint. Don’t know if my parents had a strong sense of humor or none at all.”
> Bagshott smiled politely.

None of my dictionaries of books of slang have offered any hints as to why that name would be considered humorous, but I admit that I have never been good at word-play. English nicknames can range from subtle to silly, which doesn't help!
Any ideas?

Comment: If it were a later book, I could see him joking about being named after the *Jaws* character. As it is, I have one very faint idea.

Comment: FWIW, Goodreads states that *A Brother for Hugh* was the original English title.

Comment: We can assume that his parents chose his first name but didn't chose his last name. So it must relate to the choice of first name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any immediate allusions that come to mind, Samuel being a common name, and [Quint](https://www.ancestry.com/name-origin?surname=quint) being somewhat uncommon but not unknown surname. In the game of piquet, the terms is sometimes used to refer to a five card straight flush or as a shortened version of "quintuplet". The surname derives from Middle English Quient, or Old French Cointe or Cuinte with a meaning of "Wise Prudent; Crafty Sly; Elegant; Vain", but that would be just the last name.

The only other thing I can think of is that he is referring to that his initialism, "S. Quint" could be read as the English word "squint" as in to peer closely.

Comment: The joke is definitely Squint.

Comment: The answer is clever, and I doubt I'll ever hear a better. Although I still wish I'd asked the question back when I first read the book: one of the older generation — people who had lived through the period — might have had another answer.
On the other hand, their answer might have been wrong all the same!